# How to work on SVNX?

Tags: svn, macos

I have to use svnX in my computer but i don't know how will i use it. Can anybody give  me idea how to work on svnX. I don't want to with commands so graphical views representation will be helpful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for guides? http://www.switchingtomac.com/tutorials/get-started-with-subversion-using-svnx/

General information about how to use SVN? like repositories, branching, tagging, commit, etc. ?

Its not clear what you exactly are looking for at what your knowledge is about the subject. Please share some more information.

Comment: Yes looking for guide. I am new with SVN and also on SVNX both.

Comment: The URL above, "Get Started with Subversion Using SvnX" is really only about how to install Subversion.  A novice -- especially a novice who hasn't used another subversion client or command-line subversion -- will be left confused.  This link is old (and the instructions for installing command-line subversion don't work), but more thorough: http://blogjunkie.net/2010/08/absolute-basic-subversion-for-newbies-with-svnx